# How can I test my Windows app in multiple monitor setup?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, multiple-monitors

I code for Windows desktop platform and I need to test my desktop app in a multiple monitor configuration. What is the easiest way to do that? (Well, besides me buying the needed hardware...) I guess I'm asking about a virtual platform to do that. (It seems like VMware workstation does not support such feature.)

Comment: I think you already know the *easiest* way...  Attach another monitor.  You don't need to buy it.  You can borrow it, if your display adapter supports multiple outputs.  Or hook it up to your TV.  Or visit a friend who has multiple displays.  If you're gonna buy anything, get something super cheap second-hand.

Comment: Yeah... thanks. I was hoping for a VM type solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) can emulate a system with up to eight monitors.

Comment: I'm still not exactly clear how to configure it there. So I installed Windows 7 into the VirtualBox's VM, then before I booted it up I went to Machine -> Settings -> Display -> Monitor Count = 2 and then set video memory to 128MB, OK'ed it and booted up guest Windows 7. And now what? Windows 7 still loads in a single VM window...

Comment: Have you installed the Guest Additions?

Comment: OK, that did the trick. Then one can select monitors in the VM in Windows display properties. Thank you very much for your suggestion!